# A norm inequality for operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities, operator-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be self-adjoint operators of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($A$ and $B$ unbounded), $A\geq 0$, $B \geq 0$, with $\sqrt{A} C$ and $\sqrt{B} C$ bounded. Is the following inequality true for some constant $c \geq 0$, where $\left| \! \left| \cdot \right| \! \right|$ is the operator norm,
\begin{align*}
     \left| \! \left| \sqrt{A+B} C \right| \! \right| \leq c \left| \! \left| \sqrt{A} C \right| \! \right| + c \left| \! \left| \sqrt{B} C \right| \! \right| ?
 \end{align*}

Comment: Should $A$ be $B$ in the last term?

Comment: Yes thanks (and sorry)

Comment: Also, do you need some more assumptions to ensure that $A+B$ is self adjoint?

Comment: Yes you can assume that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
\|\sqrt{A+B}Cx\|^2=(\sqrt{A+B}Cx,\sqrt{A+B}Cx)=\\
((A+B)Cx,Cx)=(ACx,Cx)+(BCx,Cx)=\|\sqrt{A}Cx\|^2+\|\sqrt{B}Cx\|^2,
$$
taking the supremum over unit vectors $x$ we get
$$
\|\sqrt{A+B}C\|^2\leqslant \|\sqrt{A}C\|^2+\|\sqrt{B}C\|^2\leqslant (\|\sqrt{A}C\|+\|\sqrt{B}C\|)^2.
$$

Answer (score 6):

For any unit vector $x\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$\|\sqrt{A+B}\,Cx\|^2=(\sqrt{A+B}\,Cx,\sqrt{A+B}\,Cx)
=(ACx,Cx)+(BCx,Cx)=\|\sqrt A\,Cx\|^2+\|\sqrt B\,Cx\|^2
\le(\|\sqrt A\,Cx\|^2+\|\sqrt B\,Cx\|)^2
\le(\|\sqrt A\,C\|+\|\sqrt B\,C\|)^2.$$
So,
$$\|\sqrt{A+B}\,C\|\le\|\sqrt A\,C\|+\|\sqrt B\,C\|.$$